# Can I customize column names for an abstract domain class in Grails?

Tags: grails, abstract-class, last-modified, datecreated

I have an Abstract Domain Class in Grails wich has fields that all the other class will use, so the other class extends of it. This field are audit fields. I use the automatic timestamp fields: `dateCreated` and `LastUpdated` and two other `String` fields.

I need the columns to have specific names, and for some reason the column name mapping is not working.

```
static mapping = {
    createUser column: "AUDI_TCREATE_USER"
    editUser column: "AUDI_TEDIT_USER"
    dateCreated column: "AUDI_DDATE_CREATED"
    lastUpdated column: "AUDI_DDATE_MODIFIED"
    tablePerHierarchy false
}

String createUser
String editUser
Date dateCreated
Date lastUpdated
```

It does not throw any errors but it just keeps the original column name in the DB for every field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have to define mappings in each domain class, which extends your abstract domain class.
I am speaking about grails 1.3.x.

Comment: I am using Grails 1.3.7. Guess I'll have to do it in every domain class. Thanks anyway.